# I have created a MS Teams bot. We are seeing the following messages when someone interact with our bot in personal chat

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

We are seeing the following messages when someone interact with our bot in personal chat. This started showing recently. If there is a way, we can remove the message showing up in the bot chat window? We have not yet changed anything so I am not sure if there was any specific update from MS Teams that causing this.

[image]

Comment: This message is by design. If user wants to get rid of the message, user need to install that app in personal scope by clicking 'Add app', which is optional.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, but we do not have any personal scope defined for the bot so even if user try to click on 'Add App', they see 'Add to team' button because that's the only option we give.

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest file?